# Gradle task similar to ivy resolve?

Tags: gradle, ivy, resolve

I am working on a project on the side of the main project. The main project used to use ivy so my side project can take advantage of the ivy.xmls and do ivy:resolve to solve all dependencies into a cache.

The main project has moved to gradle and I was wondering if there is a task in the gradle API that can populate gradle cache when I only have the gradle build files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish the same thing with Gradle by configuring a task to copy a configuration to a destination.

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "$buildDir/deps"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try today.